# CSS Selector - get element knowing element childs

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors

I want to get `tr` element which contains `span.selected` in correct column. I need to do it using one selector.

It finds if element exists:

```
By.CssSelector("tr[role='row'].jqgrow td[aria-describedby$='Default'] span.selected")
```

but it return `span.selected` IWebElement.. How can I get `tr[role='row'].jqgrow` IWebElement (using CssSelector or XPath)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may work with XPath

```
//tr[@role='row']
    [contains(@class, 'jqgrow')]
    [.//td[ends-with(@aria-describedby, 'Default')][.//span[contains(@class, 'selected')]]]
```

If elements have multiple classes, it's safer (and less readable) to replace the various `contains(@class, 'jqgrow')` with `(@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' jqgrow '))` (trick borrowed from Python's `cssselect`)

I don't think you can achieve that with CSS selectors alone.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe CSS lets you do that, as you need a parent selector:

[CSS selector for "foo that contains bar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar).

You will need to use XPath, which has the ability to select parents based on a child.  You can check this post for information on using an XPath to select a parent with a specific child node:

[XPath find all elements with specific child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881179/xpath-find-all-elements-with-specific-child-node)