# How to extract a specific branch of a XML tree in HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

Giving the example:

```
<pous>
  <pou>
    <interface>
      ...
    </interface>
    <body>
      <FBD>
        ...
      </FBD>
    </body>
  </pou>
  <pou>
    <interface>
      ...
    </interface>
    <body>
      <SFC>
        ...
      </SFC>
    </body>
  </pou>
</pous>
```

I know how to obtain all the "pou" using the function atTag:

```
atTag:: (ArrowXml a) => String -> a XmlTree XmlTree
atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)
```

But how to I extract only the "pou" with the the SFC tag? Is there a clean way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `filterA` for this example

```hs
application
    = processChildren
    $ getChildren                    -- Gets the children of "pous"
    >>> filterA hasSFC
    where hasSFC =  hasName "pou"    -- Include all "pou" elements
                >>> getChildren      -- that have children
                >>> getChildren      -- that have children
                >>> hasName "SFC"    -- that have a "SFC" element

main = do
    runX $
        readDocument [] "input.xml" >>>
        application                 >>>
        writeDocument [withIndent yes] "output.xml"
```

Comment: I adapted your idea in my code and it has done the trick.
Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Haskell XPath](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-xpath) and:

```
/*/pou[body[SFC]]
```

Further reference ["XPath find all elements with specific child node"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881179/xpath-find-all-elements-with-specific-child-node)