# Select all nodes with a child that has a certain attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to select only the a elements that have a child with a c attribute. So in this case it would be only the first two a elements.

```
<alpha>
  <a id="1">
    <b c="1"/>
  </a>
  <a id="2">
    <b c="1"/>
  </a>
  <a id="3">
    <b />
  </a>
</alpha>
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? I've tried the following with no luck:

```
/alpha/a/b/*[@c]
//a[b/*[@c]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

edit: It was suggested that I consult the solutions posed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881179/xpath-find-all-elements-with-specific-child-node), however, the problem addressed in that thread is different than mine (involving child elements rather than attributes of child elements) and I haven't been able to extrapolate a solution to my problem from this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath find all elements with specific child node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881179/xpath-find-all-elements-with-specific-child-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following experssion (abbreviated syntax):

```
//a[*/@c]
```

Or you can use unabbreviated syntax:

```
/descendant::a[child::*/attribute::c]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works as expected:
//a/*[@c]

Select any node "//a" with any child "/*" with attribute c "[@c]".