# Get href from component containing another component

Tags: xpath

I would like to catch by an XPath expression the href of the second link, the one containing the span for example in this :

```
<a class="test" href="1">hey</a>
<a class="test" href="2">
    <span>blabla</span>
</a>
```

Thanks by advance!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath find all elements with specific child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881179/xpath-find-all-elements-with-specific-child-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [ ] syntaxe using parentheses around the span :
//a[(span)]/@href